# Watching the details of a normal Windows XP boot cycle

Tags: windows-xp, boot, safe-mode

Is it possible to see the details of what is going on behind the scenes/screen during booting of Windows XP? Something like the dump that is shown when booting up in safe mode.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in Windows XP. Run 'gpedit.msc' in the start/run dialogue. This will give you access to the Group Policy editor.

Under the 'User configuration', check 'administrative templates\system\scripts'. You can the 'Run logon scripts visible' option. Change the setting to enabled.

Answer (score 1):

**[BootVis](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Tweak/System-Tweak/BootVis.shtml)** is a performance trace visualization utility that you can use with Windows XP systems. You can use it to display the boot process graphically, then analyze and improve the system startup, whether from cold boot or when resuming from standby or hibernation.

Answer (score 0):

Booting into Safe Mode will show you the file names of drivers and system files as they're loaded.

(To boot to safe mode, press F8 during boot up and select "Safe mode" from resulting menu)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the `/sos` parameter in your boot.ini. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms791494.aspx